Нужна ли тут запятая перед союзом И, или это случай с присоединением?
В годы Великой Отечественной войны грызунов в Ленинграде было очень много(?) и они переносили опасные болезни.

Этот вопрос похож на: Запятая в сложносочинненом предложении. Если вы считаете его другим, пожалуйста, отредактируйте вопрос, чётко обозначив отличие и/или почему ответы на вопрос не помогли в вашем случае.

Правильно:
В годы Великой Отечественной войны грызунов в Ленинграде было очень мнОго, и они переносили опасные болЕзни.
Пояснение

Обстоятельство может быть общим элементом, и кажется, что запятая не нужна.

Но предложения неоднородные, зависимые, так как второе сообщение распространяет первое (грызуны, они). Поэтому относим обстоятельство к первому предложению и ставим запятую.

Как это объяснить по семантике?  Грызуны в любое время переносят опасные болезни.


Сравнить: В годы войны грызунов было много и частотность заболеваний увеличилась. Нет запятой.
